# Function Contain Specific String Return a string

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new to javascript I am trying to create a function that I wanted to call if the string contains (-) will return a string value of "00" but if not will remain the same value. I will really appreciate any help or advice thank you.

```
example
val1= -01
expected output is =00


val2= 03
expected output:03
```

Code but not working

I used it like

```
myFunction(val1);
```

but this still return same value even string contains this -

```
function myFunction(myFunction) {

  var n = myFunction.includes("-");
  if (n =="true"){
      return "00:00";
  }else{
      return myFunction;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
 as below:

```js
var val1= '-01';
var val2= '03';

function myFunction(s){
    return s.includes('-') ? '00' : s;
}

console.log(myFunction(val1));
console.log(myFunction(val2));
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're checking if the result of calling `includes` is equal to the string `"true"`, which won't be the case. Simply replacing your `if` statement with `if(n)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(word) {

  if (word.includes("-")) {
    return "00";
  }

  else {
    return word;
  }
}

console.log(myFunction("-01"));
console.log(myFunction("02"));
```

Don't use `myFunction` as both the name of a function and its argument. It's a Bad Idea.

Comment: You suggest to not use `myFunction` as the name for the function and the argument, but you do not explain why the code really failing. Because the naming might be a bad idea but does not explain why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here.

Try this:

```
function myFunction(myString) {

  if (myString.includes("-")) {
      return "00:00";
  }else{
      return myString;
  }
```

1. Use *different* names for the function ("myFunction") and the function parameter ("myString").
2. Use the keyword "true", instead of the string "true".  Or even better, just use a boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper names for your functions and variables. Further, boolean checks can be simplified directly. Try this

```
function myFunction(str) {
   if (str.includes("-")) {
     return "00";
   } else {
     return str;
   }
}
```

An other way would be to use the ternary operator.

```
function myFunction(str) {
    return str.includes("-") ? "00" : str
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function mycontain(s) {
  // check if desired token exists then return special or original
  return s.includes('-') ? '00' : s
}
```